# « Un beau jour de dimanche »

Tags: sens, expressions, formulation-idiomatique, france

*La Petite Fadette*, George Sand

> Mais, comme il n’est secret qui puisse durer,
> voilà qu’un beau jour de dimanche, Sylvinet,
> passant le long du mur du cimetière, entendit la
> voix de son besson qui parlait à deux pas de lui,
> derrière le retour que faisait le mur.

Apparemment, on ne dit plus « un jour de dimanche ».

[image]

[jour de dimanche](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22jour%20de%20dimanche%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

1. Est-ce que l'on doit absolument éviter cette construction de nos jours ?
2. Est-ce qu'il y aurait une raison apparente pour la disparition de cette forme ? Elle était courante, mais elle est à présent très rare les récentes occurrences sont dues à des études modernes de vieux textes).
3. Il n'est pas difficile de voir que « un jour de dimanche » serait souvent « traduit » par « un dimanche », mais comment transposer  « un beau jour de dimanche » en français moderne ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'expression n'est ni morte ni, je pense, même moribonde. Si « un jour de dimanche » semble de moins en moins usité, il n'en va pas forcément de même pour « un **beau** jour de dimanche », sans doute parce que « un beau jour de… » est devenu, de nos jours du moins, une formule quasi figée.

Pour « beau jour de dimanche » on obtient :

[image]

Exemple (2018), trouvé [ici](https://www.tripadvisor.fr/ShowUserReviews-g1076283-d5957559-r588315952-McDonald_s-Neufchateau_Vosges_Grand_Est.html) :

> Un beau jour de dimanche au mois de juin, j'ai eu l'idée d'aller
> prendre une glace à ce mac donalds avec mes deux enfants et ma femme.

Autre exemple (non daté), trouvé [ici](http://www.allo-garagistes.fr/specialites/garage-honda/garage-Honda-ouvert-le-dimanche.html) :

> Tous les automobilistes savent tous [*sic*] combien il est fâcheux de tomber
> en panne un beau jour de dimanche, spécialement si l’on se trouve dans
> un lieu où l’on n’a pas l’habitude d’être.

Answer (score 4):

1. Tout dépend d'à qui on s'adresse mais on ne devrait rien s'interdire à priori.
2. Un beau dimanche.

Comment: Le problème de cette transposition c'est qu'un beau dimanche n'est pas beau, pas nécessairement. (A.− [L'idée dominante est celle de hasard, d'imprévisibilité]
− Un beau jour. Un certain jour. Un beau matin, un beau soir )

Comment: Un *beau jour de dimanche* ne me parait ni plus beau ni moins beau qu'un *beau dimanche* mais si tu veux insister sur le fait que ce dimanche doit être *beau*, tu peux écrire *une belle journée de dimanche*

Comment: Autrement dit, comme « journée » et jour sont commutables, « un beau jour de dimanche » est tout aussi valide.

Comment: *Jour* et *journée* ne sont pas souvent interchangeables. *Un beau jour* suppose plus le hasard, *une belle journée* la météo.

Comment: Il n'en reste pas moins que le complément prépositionnel « de dimanche » est ajouté selon la même relation ; ça soulève la question de la disparition progressive de ce complément.